# in LTE Gx (Diameter) Interface how would transactions like Re-Auth Req/Ans mapped to IMSI?

Tags: lte, 4g, diameter-protocol

in LTE Gx (Diameter) Interface how would transactions like Re-Auth Req/Ans  mapped to IMSI? these transactions don't have Subscription ID and User-Name APN and same thing for other Diameter Interfaces transactions that are missing Subscription ID and User-Name APN, if you can give me an insight I  will greatly appreciated it!

Answer (score 1):

Gx is session based, which means that the session will be from the initial CCR till the end. The RAR will be part of some existing session. There shall a mapping between session id vs the subscriber details in PCRF to process the RAR request.

Answer (score 0):

Lava,

Check the following link may be helpful.
http://tech.queryhome.com/146064/diameter-interface-would-transactions-like-auth-mapped-imsi?show=146070#a146070